# XGBoost - Linear Tree

Tags: boosting, lightgbm, boosted-regression-trees

I’ve been reading about linear tree models particularly the [linear-tree](https://github.com/cerlymarco/linear-tree) package and the option to use linear trees in *LightGBM* if one sets the parameter `linear_tree` to True. However I am confused by *XGBoost’s* `gblinear` booster. Previous resources I found on stats.exchange haven’t been helpful and there is very little out there on `gblinear`. Does `gblinear` mean that the leaves have linear models making it a linear tree model?

Answer (score 2):

The [`gblinear`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html#parameters-for-linear-booster-booster-gblinear) booster is an ensemble of generalised linear regression models that is trained using (variants of) gradient descent. As such the concept of a leaf or leaves is inapplicable in the case of a `gblinear` booster as it uses linear functions only. Effectively a `gblinear` booster is an [elastic net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization) GLM as we primarily control the L1 and L2 regularisation parameters, it does *not* have any tree structure associated with it.

What you describe where "*leaves have linear models*" is essentially the methodology of [Cubist](https://www.rulequest.com/cubist-info.html) (or M5) where a tree is grown such that the terminal leaves contain linear regression models. As you note, LightGBM's [`linear_tree`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#linear_tree) does that if one wants to experiment with it further.

Comment: Got it, thanks @usεr11852. If XGBoost's `gblinear` is a GLM, why does it have the letter "b" in it. Makes it seem like it is a GBM where the "_leaves have linear models_". It's confusing because then the [linear-tree package](https://github.com/cerlymarco/linear-tree), "a python library to build Model Trees with Linear Models at the leaves", has their own Linear Boosting available. In addition, LightGBM has their `linear_tree` option.

Comment: Because a `gblinear` object is fitted sequentially by combining GLM and then combines them together, it is a booster. Just combing GLMs still gives you a GLM. (Hm, I will clarify this point in answer.)

Comment: BTW, if this post is useful for you, you can upvote it, and it resolves your ask you consider accepting it as an answer.

Comment: I tried to when you first responded but I got the message "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded". Thank you for the help though @usεr11852

Comment: Oh, right, no worries. I mentioned it because sometimes new users don't immediately understand the voting concept. Go forth and boost! :)